# I need to fully automate sql server restores , PLease help me

Tags: sql-server

I'm New to SQL Server and don't have experience in automated restores.

I need a script to restore a database from a .bak file and move the logical_data and logical_log files to a specific path.

I can do:

```
restore filelistonly from disk='D:\backups\my_backup.bak'
```

This will give me a result set with a column LogicalName. Next I need to use the logical names from the result set in the restore command:

```
restore database my_db_name
from disk='d:\backups\my_backups.bak' 
with file=1, 
move 'logical_data_file' to 'd:\data\mydb.mdf', 
move 'logical_log_file' to 'd:\data\mylog.ldf'
```

How do I capture the logical names from the first result set into variables that can be supplied to the "move" command?

I think the solution might be trivial, but I'm pretty new to SQL Server.

Comment: Please help me i got stuck some where please

Comment: if you do a search you will find lot of options to do this, check this [detailed answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2515664/1297603) for example

Comment: that is not working for me i have tried that one also

Comment: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 111
Must declare the scalar variable "@v_strExecSQL".

Comment: No script will cover 100% your specific case, you will need to put some effort on your side to tune it for your own environment, even a tool or product you buy for the task will need some configuration on your side, you can't simple expect to have something that runs and instantly covers all your needs

Comment: Hey sorry man , i will put my effort but i am not able to understand the concept where i need to supply the input parameters like that , I am very new to this ....Plese help me how to pass the parameters  rest i will take care or if you have any kind of doc..it would be great help for me thanks in advacne

Answer (score 2):

I have built an exactly similar system for my developers, where I automate the restores of daily backups from production and I used a very similar method to what you use.

The solution I used, for your specific problem, can be found below in a short code-snippet, where `@backupName` is a variable where I previously stored the path for the backup to be restored.

```
create table #tmp (
    logicalName                 nvarchar(max)
    , physicalName              nvarchar(max)
    , type                      char(1)
    , fileGroupName             nvarchar(max)
    , size                      numeric(20, 0)
    , maxSize                   numeric(20,0)
    , field                     numeric(25,0)
    , creteLSN                  numeric(25,0)
    , dropLSN                   numeric(25,0)
    , uniqueid                  uniqueidentifier
    , readOnlyLSN               numeric(25,0) 
    , readWriteLSN              numeric(25,0) 
    , backupSizeInBytes         bigint
    , sourceBlockSize           int
    , fileGroupId               int
    , logGroupGuid              uniqueidentifier
    , differentialBaseLSN       numeric(25,0)
    , differentialBaseGuid      uniqueidentifier
    , isReadOnly                bit
    , isPresent                 bit
    , TDETThumbPrint            nvarchar(max));

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'RESTORE FILELISTONLY from disk = @dbVar';
declare @paramDefinition nvarchar(max);

set @paramDefinition = '@dbVar nvarchar(max)';

insert into #tmp 
exec sp_executesql @sql, @paramDefinition, @dbVar = @backupName;

declare @logicalName_Data nvarchar(max)
    , @logicalName_Log nvarchar(max)

select @logicalName_Data = logicalName
from #tmp
where type = 'D';

select @logicalName_Log = logicalName
from #tmp
where type = 'L';

set @paramDefinition = '@dbName nvarchar(max), @filePath nvarchar(max), @LNameData nvarchar(max), @LDataLocation nvarchar(max), @LNameLog nvarchar(max), @LLogLocation nvarchar(max)';

set @sql = 'restore database @dbName 
            from disk = @filePath 
            with move @LNameData to @LDataLocation
                , move @LNameLog to @LLogLocation
                , recovery;';

declare @datafile nvarchar(max) = 'C:\DBFiles\' + @databaseName + '.mdf'
    , @logfile nvarchar(max) = 'C:\DBFiles\' + @databaseName + '.ldf';

exec sp_executesql @sql, @paramDefinition
            , @dbName = @databaseName
            , @filePath = @backupName
            , @LNameData = @logicalName_Data
            , @LDataLocation = @datafile
            , @LNameLog = @logicalName_Log
            , @LLogLocation = @logfile;
```

This is mostly what I used for restoring my databases. This is actually only some of the code I use to restore the databases since the full solution involves a restore queue and a mechanism of copying, with a cycle of re-attempts of restoring the backup if for any reason they fail, logging the errors during backup etc.

I had to copy multiple snippets off my restore script to get the code above, so hopefully I didn't miss anything and it's what you need or just enough to adjust your solution.

**Update:**

What is also important to be mentioned is that this script was built to work for databases with **1 data file** and **1 log file**. It will need to be adjusted if you need to move multiple files to different disk drives.

Comment: So what are the parameters i need to supply kindly helo e @Radu

Comment: @DBA_Fresher this isn't a plug-and-go solution. You need to adjust it to your needs. Please read, understand it and modify it for your needs. (I'm not going to do that for you and I believe I provided enough details in my answer as to what needs to be additionally defined for this to work).

Comment: I am not able to understand the code, please guide me thanks in advance

Comment: @DBA_Fresher I can't do that right now, I'm a DBA on the job now as well (hopefully my boss doesn't see what I'm doing now). I suggest you take time to read it thoroughly. The big idea in my script is that I store the results of `restore filelistonly` in a temporary table, which I previously create, so that I can use the names of the `Data File` and `Log File` in the `RESTORE` command and so that I don't have to hardcode anything. Sorry, but I can't do anything more than this for you at the moment.

Comment: If nothing from what is above looks familiar I suggest you do a web-search for `temporary tables` , `variables` and `dynamic sql` and have a few 30-45 minutes of solid reading to get a basic grasp of the things I use in my script.

Comment: EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Brent Ozar's *sp_DatabaseRestore* [Open Source Database Restore Stored Procedure](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/databaserestore-open-source-database-restore-stored-procedure/).

Create it on your server(s), and all you have to do is call the procedure and pass in the parameters, and it does the restore for you.  The link I posted has some examples.

Comment: I am getting this error while supplying the parameters Getting default msg 5000 error getting ......please help me